# create and calculate z score column in SQL (mariadb)

Tags: sql, xampp, mariadb

As the title says, looking for a simple way to calculate the z score for each row in a column.

I tried the following, and don't know why it doesn't work (returns error ER_INVALID_GROUP_FUNC_USE)

```
ALTER TABLE tbl
ADD z_score INT;

UPDATE tbl
SET z_score = (values - avg(values))/ stddev(values)
WHERE values IS NOT NULL;
```

I've seen ways of doing it online, but they feel more complicated than is necessary.

Comment: Please: 1) Describe how do you want to calculate additional column. 2) Should it be calculated and persistent or maybe it sould just appear in the output? 3) Provide sample data and desired output in text format. 4) Describe what "it doesn't work" means. 5) Add the tag of your DBMS

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 2):

In order to calculate the z-score, you need the average and standard deviation.  You don't specify the database you are using, but one method that should work in (almost) all databases is a subquery:

```
UPDATE tbl
    SET z_score = (SELECT (tbl.values - avg(tbl2.values)) / stddev(tbl2.values)
                   FROM tbl tbl2
                  )
WHERE values IS NOT NULL;
```

Most databases also support some sort of `JOIN` operation in the `UPDATE`, but the syntax depends on the database.

EDIT:

MariaDB does not support the above Standard SQL syntax.  Instead, you can use a `CROSS JOIN`:

```
UPDATE tbl CROSS JOIN
       (SELECT AVG(values) as avg_values, STDDEV(values) as stddev_values
        FROM tbl
       ) t2
    SET tbl2.z_score = (tbl.values - avg_values) / NULLIF(stddev_values, 0)
WHERE values IS NOT NULL AND stddev_values <> 0;
```

Comment: Much appreciated - updated the tag as you said. I'm using MariaDB. Just got started creating and managing my own DB so apologies for the gaps and thanks for working with them to answer my question. From what I can see in the documentation, this db won't allow a select subquery from the same table.